# Monte Carlo dice roll and bit coin simulation

Tags: java, random, montecarlo, dice

in one of my recent labs we were asked to do a Monte Carlo simulation in java, the question was worded very weirdly, but from what I can gather we needed to simulate rolling a dice and mining a bitcoin. Basically every 200 rolls a bitcoin was mined but we only wanted to know the number of times that it takes to roll a six when a bitcoin is mined, and then we need to get the average number of rolls that we rolled a 6. I have a basic solution done out but its not right and the bitcoin part is confusing me, does anyone know how I could improve my code.

```
import java.util.*; 

 public class monteCarloDiceRollBitCoin
 {

     public static void main (String args[])
     {  

         Random rand = new Random();
         int dice = 0;
         int rolled = 0; 
         Random bitCoin = new Random();
         int bitcoinMined = 0;  
         int times = 0; 




            for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++){ //MonteCarlo simulation 1,000 
             times 

                for(int counter = 0; counter <=200; counter++)
                {

                    dice = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // 6 is the maximum and the 
                    1 is our minimum, like simulating a dice roll
                    bitcoinMined = bitCoin.nextInt(200);

                        if(dice==6 && counter == 200)
                        {
                            rolled++; //increment the rolled variable if 
                            dice returns a 6
                            bitcoinMined++; // when counter is 200 a bitcoin 
                            has been mined
                        }

                        /*if(counter == 300)
                        {
                            bitCoin++; 
                        }*/




                       }



                /*int average = rolled/bitCoin;
                System.out.println("Six was rolled " + rolled + "times");
                System.out.println(bitCoin + "bitcoin(s) were mined");
                System.out.println("The average number that a six was rolled 
                is" + average);*/
             }
                int average = rolled/bitcoinMined;
                System.out.println(" Six was rolled " + rolled + "times ");
                System.out.println(bitcoinMined + " bitcoin(s) were mined 
                ");
                System.out.println(" The average number that a six was 
                rolled is " + average);

             }
            }
```

I have a times variable declared that I haven't used because I'm just trying to figure out where to put it, please bear in mind I'm still relatively new to programming and even my demonstrators said it was a very weird question to give us.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Frank, unfortunately I can’t actually elaborate because that’s all we were told in the lab, the demonstrators in the lab weren’t quite sure about it either, but thank you for your help! It’s greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The question is indeed a little vague.
I don't understand what you mean with "Average time a six was rolled", if you can explain I will adapt the code...

From what I can understand from your explanation I made this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MonteCarloDiceRollBitCoin {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int rolled = 0;
    int bitcoinMined = 0;
    int bitcoinMinedAtSix = 0;
    int sixCounter=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { // MonteCarlo simulation 1000000 times
        int dice = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // 6 is the maximum and the 1 is our minimum, like simulating a dice roll
        if (dice == 6) {
            rolled++; // increment the rolled variable if dice returns a 6
        }
        if ((i+1) % 200 == 0) {
            bitcoinMined++; // increment counter divides by 200 : bitcoin has been mined
            if(sixCounter==0) {
                sixCounter=rolled; // this will remember the amount of sixRoled to mine the FIRST bitcoin.
            }
            if (dice == 6) {
                bitcoinMinedAtSix++; // and we also have a dice=6
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Six was rolled " + rolled + " times.");
    System.out.println("Six was rolled " + sixCounter + " times before the first bitcoin was mined.");
    System.out.println(bitcoinMined + " bitcoin(s) were mined.");
    System.out.println(bitcoinMinedAtSix + " bitcoin(s) at Dice=6 were mined.");
    }
}
```